# Find CSS class names that are not inside comments using Regular Expressions

Tags: css, regex, class, comments

I'm trying to replace all class names in a CSS file. I am using JavaScript/Node.js.

My current solution is this: `/\.[a-z][a-z0-9-_]*/g`.
At the end of the file is a comment that references the source map file: `/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */`. Now the file extensions of that URL also get replaced.

Given the following input:

```
.text-center { text-align: center; }
table.simple{background:#fff;}.bg-white{background:#fff;}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
/*
Example comment file.css
*/
```

the result is:

```
.a { text-align: center; }
table.a{background:#fff;}.a{background:#fff;}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.a.a */
/*
Example comment file.a
*/
```

what I want is:

```
.a { text-align: center; }
table.a{background:#fff;}.a{background:#fff;}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
/*
Example comment file.css
*/
```

How do I have to change my RegEx so it does only match class names, that are outside of comments (`//` comments are not relevant here)?

Comment: Which regex engine/language are you using?

Comment: I am using JavaScript/Node.js @ctwheels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Both of these approaches work in different cases like classes between ids or multiple classes in selection:*

```
.class-a, #id-a, .class-b:hover {}
```

---

### First approach

In this first approach you can match both comment section and CSS classes then replace class names while they are matched and leave comments intact:

```
\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|(\.[a-z_-][\w-]*)(?=[^{}]*{)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 Match comments    Match and capture classes
```

Breakdown:

```
\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/    # Match a comment block
|                   # Or
(                   # Start of capturing group #1
    \.[a-z_-][\w-]* # Match a CSS class name
)                   # End of CG #1
(?=                 # Start of a positive lookahead
    [^{}]*{         # Class should be followed by a `{` (may not be immediately)
)                   # End of lookahead
```

JS code:

```js
var str = `.text-center { text-align: center; }
table.simple{background:#fff;}.bg-white{background:#fff;}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
/*
Example comment file.css
*/`

console.log(str.replace(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|(\.[a-z_-][\w-]*)(?=[^{}]*{[^{}]*})/g,
    function($0, $1) {
        return $1 ? '.a' : $0; // If a class is matched ...
    }
));
```

### Second approach

If you don't think in comments such occurrences will exist:

```
/* style.css {css file} */
```

you can omit matching comments in first approach:

```
\.[a-z_-][\w-]*(?=[^{}]*{[^{}]*})
                         ^^^^^^^ 
             Added for a more strict selection
```

[RegEx live demo](https://regex101.com/r/QzMfak/1)

JS code:

```js
var str = `.text-center { text-align: center; }
table.simple{background:#fff;}.bg-white{background:#fff;}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
/*
Example comment file.css
*/`

console.log(str.replace(/\.[a-z_-][\w-]*(?=[^{}]*{[^{}]*})/g, '.a'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
\.[^{\s]*(?=\s*{)
```

and replace each match with `.a`

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/24zedc/4/)**

**Explanation:**

- `\.` - matches a `.`
- `[^{\n]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is neither a white-space nor `{`
- `(?=\s*{)` - positive lookahead to make sure that the current position is followed by 0+ whitespaces followed by `{`.

---

Now, the above regex would fail if we have comments of the format

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map {*/
```

i.e, `{` present after `css.map` inside a comment. So, to handle such a case, you can use the following regex(almost similar to the previous regex. Just one more negative lookahead to the regex)

```
\.[^{\s]*(?=\s*{)(?!(?:(?!\/\*)[\s\S])*\*\/)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/24zedc/7/)**

**Explanation:**

- `\.[^{\s]*(?=\s*{)` - similar to the previous regex
- `(?!(?:(?!\/\*)[\s\S])*\*\/)` - Negative lookahead to make sure that the current position(position right after the `.classname`) is not present within a comment of the form `/*...*/`

  - `(?!....` - negative lookahead
  - `(?:(?!\/\*)[\s\S])*` - [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/5331061) to match 0+ occurrences of any character greedily, which does not begin with the sequence `/*`
  - `\*\/` - matches `*/`

Comment: This does not work for selectors with multiple classes. I missed specifying that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work with the following RegEx in **pcre flavor**

```
/(\/\*)?(?(1)(.*\*\/)|(\.[a-z][a-z0-9-_]*))/g
```

I'm using a conditional statement. Whenever it detects a start of a comment, it does not look for a class name but for the end of the comment. However, **this does not work for comments on multiple lines**. The class names are the third capturing group. So to replace class names, only touch matches that contain the capturing group 3.

I didn't notice I was using pcre instead of javascript on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and ended up with a syntax error in my JS code. I'm now working on finding a solution that works for JS.

Edit:

I now ported it to JS:

```
/(?=\/\*)|(\.[a-z][a-z0-9-_]*)(?!.*\*\/)/g
```

**I still have to find a way to get it to work with multiple lines.**

Answer (score -1):

With the following regex you should be able to extract all class-names from your css file, which are not in comment.
It´s important that the class name start with a dot (.)

Regex:

```
/^.[a-z][a-z0-9-_].*?[\s]/mg
```

[image]

Comment: The first dot in your regex does not represent a dot. You meant `\.` rather than `^.`

Comment: This doesn't work for me since I'm also dealing with minified code. Example: `p.text-center{}.text-center{}`